# Can I delete rows/replace table based on temp table

Tags: postgresql, duplicates, sql-delete, temp-tables, row-number

This code gives me a table of the unique values (without duplicates):

```
SELECT id, firstname, lastname, startdate, position
FROM  (
   SELECT id, firstname, lastname, startdate, position,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY (firstname, lastname) ORDER BY startdate DESC) rn
   FROM people
   ) tmp
WHERE rn = 1;
```

What syntax would replace the current table with just the results of this one?

Alternatively, I could use `WHERE rn <> 1` to get all the data I want to delete, but again, I am struggling to get the syntax of the `DELETE` right using this method.

Comment: I'm thinking this question needs some more thought and information. I'm not seeing ```DELETE``` in the example.  Furthermore you seem to be wanting to do an ```INSERT ``` or ```UPDATE```("What syntax would replace the current table with just the results of this one?") What is the current table?

Comment: This is a good discussion of several different options in the question and answers if you ignore the "slowness" issue:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47402098/postgresql-slow-delete-from-where-exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming values in `firstname`, `lastname` and `startdate` are never `NULL`, this simple query with a `NOT EXISTS` anti-semi-join does the job:

```sql
DELETE FROM people AS p
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM people AS p1
   WHERE  p1.firstname = p.firstname
   AND    p1.lastname  = p.lastname
   AND    p1.startdate > p.startdate
   );
```

It deletes every row where a *newer* copy exists, effectively keeping the latest row per group of peers. (Of course, `(firstname, lastname)` is a poor way of establishing identity. There are many distinct people with identical names. The demo may be simplified ...)

Can there be identical values in `startdate`? Then you need a tiebreaker ...

Typically faster than using a subquery with `row_number()`. There are a hundred and one ways to make this faster, depending on your precise situation and requirements. See:

- [How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54418/how-do-i-or-can-i-select-distinct-on-multiple-columns/12632129#12632129)

If compared columns can be `NULL`, consider:

- [How to delete duplicate rows without unique identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26769454/how-to-delete-duplicate-rows-without-unique-identifier/26773018#26773018)

There is a whole dedicated tag for [duplicate-removal](/questions/tagged/duplicate-removal). Combine it with [postgres](/questions/tagged/postgres) to narrow down:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/duplicates+postgresql

Comment: Your method looks much more simple than what I was trying to do. The example code isn't my exact situation. I have a serial_no for each row that has duplicates. The compared date doesn't have nulls, but there can be ties. Can you elaborate on how I could include a tie breaker?

Comment: @tuskity: Please clarify the question accordingly. Tell us what ties can happen and how you *want* to break ties, then I can tell you how to implement it. You might alternatively start a new question for this with details.

Comment: I set up a new question for the topic here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63005307/how-to-break-ties-when-comparing-columns-in-sql