# How to break ties when comparing columns in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates, greatest-n-per-group, sql-delete

I am trying to delete duplicates in Postgres. I am using this as the base of my query:

```
DELETE FROM case_file as p
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT FROM case_file as p1
    WHERE p1.serial_no = p.serial_no
    AND p1.cfh_status_dt < p.cfh_status_dt
    );
```

It works well, except that when the dates `cfh_status_dt` are equal then neither of the records are removed.

For rows that have the same serial_no and the date is the same, I would like to keep the one that has a registration_no (if any do, this column also has NULLS).

Is there a way I can do this with all one query, possibly with a case statement or another simple comparison?

Comment: `I would like to keep the one that has a registration_no (if any do, this column also has NULLS).` So can there be more than one among ties  with `registration_no IS NOT NULL`?

Comment: And what to do if registration_no is null for all rows? Keep the one and delete others?

Comment: Also, is there a PK or any UNIQUE (combination of) column(s). An exact table definition (`CRATE TABLE` statement) showing data types and constraints always helps to clarify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
DELETE FROM case_file AS p
WHERE  id NOT IN (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (serial_no) id  -- id = PK
   FROM   case_file 
   ORDER  BY serial_no, cfh_status_dt DESC, registration_no
   );
```

This keeps the (one) latest row per `serial_no`, choosing the smallest `registration_no` if there are multiple candidates.

`NULL` sorts last in default ascending order. So any row with a not-null `registration_no` is preferred.

If you want the *greatest* `registration_no` instead, to still sort NULL values *last*, use:

```sql
   ...
   ORDER  BY serial_no, cfh_status_dt DESC, registration_no DESC NULLS LAST
```

See:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)
- [Sort by column ASC, but NULL values first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/sort-by-column-asc-but-null-values-first/9511492#9511492)

If you have no PK (`PRIMARY KEY`) or other `UNIQUE NOT NULL` (combination of) column(s) you can use for this purpose, you can fall back to `ctid`. See:

- [How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54418/how-do-i-or-can-i-select-distinct-on-multiple-columns/12632129#12632129)

`NOT IN` is typically not the most efficient way. But this deals with duplicates involving NULL values. See:

- [How to delete duplicate rows without unique identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26769454/how-to-delete-duplicate-rows-without-unique-identifier/26773018#26773018)

If there are **many duplicates** - and you can afford to do so! - it can be (much) more efficient to create a new, pristine table of survivors and replace the old table, instead of deleting the majority of rows in the existing table.

Or create a temporary table of survivors, truncate the old and insert from the temp table. This way depending objects like views or FK constraints can stay in place. See:

- [How to delete duplicate entries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746213/how-to-delete-duplicate-entries/8826879#8826879)

**Surviving rows** are simply:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (serial_no) *
FROM   case_file 
ORDER  BY serial_no, cfh_status_dt DESC, registration_no;
```